# Laravel eagerload a custom query instead of relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a query that I want to eager load but its not working.

I have previously eager loaded relationships and its worked fine but this keeps giving me this error:

```
Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null
```

My function in the model:

```
public function update_image()
{
    return UpdateItem::where('type', 'image')->where('update_id', $this->id)->first();
}
```

And its called:

```
$updates = Update::with('project', 'update_items', 'update_image')->get();
```

I know the query itself is fine, but where is this going wrong?

Comment: 99% of the time it's due to missing `return` statements elsewhere. Can you show us where the relationships are defined?

Comment: you cant decalre relationship like this.. read about it in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships

Comment: after edit: I think you asking the wrong question, tell us what you trying to do because updating some model is not relation

Comment: For relationships you need to use special construction as @AmirBar mentioned. You cannot put here anything you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I know you can't eager load anything but relationships, but you can add your query to the relationship: in this case (I'm assuming it's one to one based on your question).

```
public function update_image()
{
     return $this->hasOne('App\UpdateItem','update_id','id')->where('type', 'image');
}
```

Comment: Thought that might be the case. Didn't know you could add query to the relationship. Thanks!